# JQuery: Binding events to dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){

    $("div").click(function(){
        $(this).clone().insertAfter( $(this) ); 
    });

});
```

This is a stupid little page where everytime a DIV is clicked, it generates a copy of it and it's placed right after it.

This seems to work fine, but only for DIVs that have been hardcoded. When the DIV is cloned and then clicked, nothing happens because the event hasn't been binded to it.

What is correct way to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [jQuery `.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("body").on("click", "div", function() {
  //...
});
```

The [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function used to be used for this purpose, but it was deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Any reason I should use on() rather than live() other than that it's been deprecated?

Comment: @user1091856 Must there be another reason? `on` with "deferred events" functions identically to `live`. It's a consolidated API.

Comment: Why do I have to select the "body" element and then specify "div" in the second argument? Couldn't I just $("div").on("click", function) ?

Comment: @user1091856 Instead of body, you can use any parent of where the div will be. The advantage of `on` is that it can look in a particular section of the page, rather than constantly analyzing the entire page for events.

Answer (score 1):

There is an special jQuery function for that, the `.live()`

```
$(function(){

    $("div").live("click",function(){
        $(this).clone().insertAfter( $(this) ); 
    });

});
```